# Check if IPv4 address is in private range

Tags: java, networking

In Python, using the IPy module you can do the following:

```
 >>> ip.iptype()
'PRIVATE'
```

Is there a library or easy way to do the equivalent in Java?

Comment: Would any of the methods in the [java.net.InetAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) class help?

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65071/test-if-given-ip-is-a-public-one

Comment: take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9729378/check-whether-the-ipaddress-is-in-private-range/9729432

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It seems that not exactly but `InetAddress` has some isXX() methods like: `isAnyLocalAddress()` and `isSiteLocalAddress()`

Comment: The `isSiteLocalAddress()` is the one I found most useful for determining private IP addresses.

Comment: `isSiteLocalAddress()` returns `false` for _127.0.0.1_, so you need to check if it's localhost with `isLoopbackAddress()` additionally.

Comment: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/65071/test-if-given-ip-is-a-public-one

Answer (score 5):

I believe Inet4Address.isSiteLocalAddress() is themethod you want.  Here is an example:

```
public final class IPFreely
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        byte[] rawAddress1 =
        { 10, 0, 0, 0 };
        byte[] rawAddress2 =
        { 10, 0, 32, 0 };
        byte[] rawAddress3 =
        { (byte) 172, 16, 0, 0 };
        byte[] rawAddress4 =
        { (byte) 192, (byte) 168, 0, 0 };

        testIpAddress(rawAddress1);
        testIpAddress(rawAddress2);
        testIpAddress(rawAddress3);
        testIpAddress(rawAddress4);
    }

    public static void testIpAddress(byte[] testAddress)
    {
        Inet4Address inet4Address;

        try
        {
            inet4Address = (Inet4Address) InetAddress.getByAddress(testAddress);

            System.out.print("inet4Address.isSiteLocalAddress(): ");
            System.out.println(inet4Address.isSiteLocalAddress());
        }
        catch (UnknownHostException exception)
        {
            System.out.println("UnknownHostException");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If [InetAddress](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html) doesn't work for you then it should be easy enough to translate following [python code](http://pypi.python.org/packages/source/I/IPy/IPy-0.75.tar.gz) to java:

```
IPv4ranges = {
    '0':                'PUBLIC',   # fall back
    '00000000':         'PRIVATE',  # 0/8
    '00001010':         'PRIVATE',  # 10/8
    '01111111':         'PRIVATE',  # 127.0/8
    '1':                'PUBLIC',   # fall back
    '1010100111111110': 'PRIVATE',  # 169.254/16
    '101011000001':     'PRIVATE',  # 172.16/12
    '1100000010101000': 'PRIVATE',  # 192.168/16
    '111':              'RESERVED'  # 224/3
    }

def iptype(self):
    if self._ipversion == 4:
        iprange = IPv4ranges
    elif self._ipversion == 6:
        iprange = IPv6ranges
    else:
        raise ValueError("only IPv4 and IPv6 supported")

    bits = self.strBin()
    for i in xrange(len(bits), 0, -1):
        if bits[:i] in iprange:
            return iprange[bits[:i]]
    return "unknown"
```

Comment: @AlexR Yup, in most cases it's not. :) I'm not python or IP pro, I just googled the module you were using in python, found the function you're using and put it up here. :)

Comment: 127.0/8 are not PRIVATE ip addresses.

Comment: 0/8 are not PRIVATE ip addresses