# Check whether the ipAddress is in private range

Tags: java

How would I check to see whether the ip address is in private category ?

```java
    if(isPrivateIPAddress(ipAddress)) {
        //do something
    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

**UPDATED ANSWER**

```java
    private static boolean isPrivateIPAddress(String ipAddress) {

            InetAddress ia = null;

            try {
                InetAddress ad = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
                byte[] ip = ad.getAddress();
                ia = InetAddress.getByAddress(ip);
            } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                return false;
            }

            return ia.isSiteLocalAddress();
        }
```

I wrote this method and it's working fine for me. But is there any case in which this method will not work ? I just wanted to make sure it will be working for every case.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8141277/check-if-ipv4-address-is-in-private-range

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a quick hack I generated to test my own address.

```
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class LocalAddress {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        InetAddress address = null;
        try {
            address = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
        }
        if (address.isSiteLocalAddress()) {
            System.out.println("Site Local Address: " + address.getHostAddress());
        } else {
            System.out.println("Routeable Address: " + address.getHostAddress());
        }
    }

}
```

EDIT:  This code has not been tested for the link local addresses, localhost, or address blocks reserved for documentation.  The first two cases have methods that return them.  The last is not referenced in the documentation of the class.

Comment: If I need to check on some random ipAddress then how I can do it? Suppose if the ipAddress is 172.18.36.81

Comment: Replace `getLocalHost()` with `getByName("172.18.36.81")`.  Read the JavaDoc for InetAddress.

Answer (score 24):

The correct method is [InetAddress.isSiteLocalAddress()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#isSiteLocalAddress()).

> Utility routine to check if the InetAddress is a site local address.
>
> Returns: a boolean indicating if the InetAddress is a site local
>   address; or false if address is not a site local unicast address.

Comment: Can you give me one example based on this. Really Appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

First of all, Private networks can use IPv4 addresses anywhere in the following ranges:

- a) 192.168.0.0 - 192.168.255.255 (65,536 IP addresses)
- b) 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 IP addresses)
- c) 10.0.0.0 - 10.255.255.255 (16,777,216 IP addresses)

As we can see from method isSiteLocalAddress in Inet4Address.java :

```
 public boolean isSiteLocalAddress() {
    // refer to RFC 1918
    // 10/8 prefix
    // 172.16/12 prefix
    // 192.168/16 prefix
    int address = holder().getAddress();
    return (((address >>> 24) & 0xFF) == 10)
        || ((((address >>> 24) & 0xFF) == 172)
            && (((address >>> 16) & 0xF0) == 16))
        || ((((address >>> 24) & 0xFF) == 192)
            && (((address >>> 16) & 0xFF) == 168));
}
```

So case b) 172.16.0.0 - 172.31.255.255 (1,048,576 IP addresses) is not satisfied. But you can easily write you own version of how to tell whether a address is private address.Here is my version:

```
import com.google.common.net.InetAddresses;

private static boolean isPrivateV4Address(String ip) {
    int address = InetAddresses.coerceToInteger(InetAddresses.forString(ip));
    return (((address >>> 24) & 0xFF) == 10)
            || ((((address >>> 24) & 0xFF) == 172) 
              && ((address >>> 16) & 0xFF) >= 16 
              && ((address >>> 16) & 0xFF) <= 31)
            || ((((address >>> 24) & 0xFF) == 192) 
              && (((address >>> 16) & 0xFF) == 168));
}
```

Comment: This answer is incorrect. Case b) is satisfied because the mask is `0xF0`. It's trivial to test that `InetAddress.getByName("172.31.255.255").isSiteLocalAddress()` returns true.

Answer (score 1):

I use this:

```
public boolean isPrivateIP(String ipAddress) {
        boolean isValid = false;

        if (ipAddress != null && !ipAddress.isEmpty()) {
            String[] ip = ipAddress.split("\\.");
            short[] ipNumber = new short[] { 
                    Short.parseShort(ip[0]), 
                    Short.parseShort(ip[1]), 
                    Short.parseShort(ip[2]),
                    Short.parseShort(ip[3])
                };

            if (ipNumber[0] == 10) { // Class A
                isValid = true;
            } else if (ipNumber[0] == 172 && (ipNumber[1] >= 16 && ipNumber[1] <= 31)) { // Class B
                isValid = true;
            } else if (ipNumber[0] == 192 && ipNumber[1] == 168) { // Class C
                isValid = true;
            }
        }

        return isValid;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

the range is

```
    // 10.x.x.x/8

    // 172.16.x.x/12

    //192.168.x.x/16
```

so we can use below code:

```
public static Boolean isIntranetIP(String IP) {
    byte[] addr = IPAddressUtil.textToNumericFormatV4(IP);
    return isIntranetIPByte(addr);
}


public static Boolean isIntranetIPByte(byte[] addr) {
    final byte B0 = addr[0];
    final byte B1 = addr[1];
    // 10.x.x.x/8
    final byte section_1 = 0x0A;
    // 172.16.x.x/12
    final byte section_2 = (byte) 0xAC;
    final byte section_3 = (byte) 0x10;
    final byte section_4 = (byte) 0x1F;
    //192.168.x.x/16
    final byte section_5 = (byte) 0xc0;
    final byte section_6 = (byte) 0xa8;

    switch (B0) {
        case section_1:
            return true;
        case section_2:
            if (B1 >= section_3 && B1 <= section_4) {
                return true;
            }
        case section_5:
            switch (B1) {
                case section_6:
                    return true;
            }
        default:
            return false;
    }
}
```